# Step by Step... Read a tag with NFC

Tags: java, android, nfc

So is anyone able to explain to me, what i need to do, in order to simply scan a tag with NFC, other than simply directing me to the android developer blog, which i do not understand?

Comment: This is a very poorly framed question. Why not explain what you have tried so far and articulate what you don't understand about the android develop blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not check out [this](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/getting-started-nfc-android) tutorial, it goes into a lot of depth reading and writing from cards. But the docs are always your best friend.

Comment: Please don't just post links because what happens if the link dies? the answer becomes useless.

Comment: Hmmm looks nice.. gonna take a look at it :)

Comment: :( Thats a tutorial on writing on a tag... i want to read from a tag.

Comment: Why not go to the official [source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html)?